# I am new to LOVE2D and this error is keep coming out every time when I run the program

Tags: compiler-errors, love2d

I start working on my platformer game using love2d for the first time but when I am trying to open tilemap(that made in program call tiled) using sti, error is keep coming out

I start working on my platformer game using love2d for the first time but when I am trying to open tilemap(that made in program call tiled) using sti, this error is keep coming out:

```
Error

sti/utils.lua:195: Could not open file kenney_pixel-platformer/Tilemap/tiles.png. Does not exist.


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'newImageData'
sti/utils.lua:195: in function 'fix_transparent_color'
sti/init.lua:102: in function 'init'
sti/init.lua:49: in function 'STI'
main.lua:4: in function 'load'
[love "callbacks.lua"]:136: in function <[love "callbacks.lua"]:135>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I've been following this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfIDHUyLpQ0&t=538s

I do not understand what is wrong. HELP

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.